# LiveData Duplicate Observers Concern

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I won't explain why this code is needed, but my question is whether the following code will lead to duplicate Observers or not:

```js
  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        initializeRecyclerView()
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestViewModel::class.java)

        updateUI()

        viewModel.getNewItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            if (it != null && it == true){
                updateUI()
            }
        })
    }
    
    fun updateUI(){
        viewModel.getItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.values = it
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }


    fun initializeRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

As `updateUI()` gets called multiple times, does this create duplicate observers of `viewmodel.getItems()`??

Comment: Yes you'll spawn new observer every time. This looks like logic that should be handled entirely within viewmodel itself, you shouldn't need to add observer everytime new items change.

Comment: Thanks Pawel - I did think this was the case.  It was recommended to me, but needs some tweaking!